# Multiply value from next row to get monthly Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data:

| Date | Index | MonthlyReturn | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 1 |
| 2023-02-01 | NULL | 3 | Group 1 |
| 2023-03-01 | NULL | 6 | Group 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 2 |
| 2023-02-01 | NULL | 4 | Group 2 |
| 2023-03-01 | NULL | 2 | Group 2 |

From this data, I want to calculate the Monthly index for each group (Index of current month * MonthlyReturn of Next Month).

Desired Output:

| Date | Index | MonthlyReturn | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 1 |
| 2023-02-01 | 30 | 3 | Group 1 |
| 2023-03-01 | 180 | 6 | Group 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 2 |
| 2023-02-01 | 40 | 4 | Group 2 |
| 2023-03-01 | 80 | 2 | Group 2 |

I am guessing the `LEAD` function would be helpful here but unable to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you include whatever code you've tried? Maybe you can be steered onto the right track.

Comment: You're going to run into the problem where the column you're multiplying is `NULL`.
You'll need to use recursion to solve the problem.

Comment: `LEAD` won't help you here, it's not recursive; it's not aware of what the prior row's expression resolved.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? I'm not well versed with recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely going to perform poorly at scale, but here's a recursive option:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Date DATE, IndexID INT, MonthlyReturn TINYINT, GroupName VARCHAR(7));
INSERT INTO @Table (Date, IndexID, MonthlyReturn, GroupName) VALUES
('2023-01-01', 10   , 0 , 'Group 1'),
('2023-02-01', NULL , 3 , 'Group 1'),
('2023-03-01', NULL , 6 , 'Group 1'),
('2023-01-01', 10   , 0 , 'Group 2'),
('2023-02-01', NULL , 4 , 'Group 2'),
('2023-03-01', NULL , 2 , 'Group 2');

;WITH rCTE AS (
SELECT Date, IndexID, MonthlyReturn, GroupName
  FROM @Table
 WHERE IndexID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT r.Date, a.IndexID*r.MonthlyReturn, r.MonthlyReturn, a.GroupName
  FROM rCTE a
    INNER JOIN @Table r
      ON a.Date = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,r.Date)
      AND a.GroupName = r.GroupName
)

SELECT *
  FROM rCTE
 ORDER BY GroupName, Date;
```

| Date | IndexID | MonthlyReturn | GroupName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 1 |
| 2023-02-01 | 30 | 3 | Group 1 |
| 2023-03-01 | 180 | 6 | Group 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 10 | 0 | Group 2 |
| 2023-02-01 | 40 | 4 | Group 2 |
| 2023-03-01 | 80 | 2 | Group 2 |

Note that I changed the names of the columns `Index` and `Group` to avoid the keywords, it's bad practice to use illegal column names.
Also note how the demo data is expressed as full DDL/DML - this is very helpful when you're asking a question.

Comment: Thank you. Will keep the suggestions in mind when asking questions from now on.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow achieve this without using Recursive CTEs?

Comment: You will have to perform recursion, as the data does not previously exist - it must be created.